# How to navigate to a template file from templateUrl in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

In Angular, within the Component.ts file @Component decorator' templateUrl property, we mention the name of the template file. I could find a VSCode extension that could visit the component.ts from the component.html file by pointing to a referenced variable and Ctrl-click. Is there a plugin to visit the template file from the component.ts?

Please note that the gotoDefinition is not working.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can try this [Angular Follow Selector](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sanderledegen.angular-follow-selector) extension.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ive already tried Angular Follow Selector. And its not installing. Trying Angular productivity pack.

Comment: Ok. Got 'Angular Follow Selector' working

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Angular Follow Selector' extension

Answer (score 1):

Install the Plugin "Angular Language Service". Place the cursor on the filename of the template and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> ("go to definiton").

For some reason, ctrl + click does not work